# Static library not linking when using -l and -L flags?

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries

So, I have a static library called `libtree-sitter.a` that I'm trying to use. Here is the compilation command from the [documentation](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/using-parsers#an-example-program):

```bash
clang                                   \
  -I tree-sitter/lib/include            \
  test-json-parser.c                    \
  tree-sitter-json/src/parser.c         \
  tree-sitter/libtree-sitter.a          \
  -o test-json-parser
```

The above command successfully compiles and the executable works correctly. I tried changing the loading of the static library into flags so I could make my build system more generic. My changes are below:

```bash
clang                                   \
  -I tree-sitter/lib/include            \
  test-json-parser.c                    \
  tree-sitter-json/src/parser.c         \
  -o test-json-parser                   \
  -Ltree-sitter -ltree-sitter
```

This compiles, but running the executable gives this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtree-sitter.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/jason/Downloads/tree sitter test/test-json-parser
  Reason: image not found
```

Can someone please explain the difference between those two examples? From my understanding of `-l` and `-L`, it should still find the library in the same place. What is an equivalent combination of flags so I can make loading libraries more generic and easily integrable with Makefile templates (I am using [this one](http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/articles/make/#improved-automatic-dependency-tracking))? Thanks for reading.

Comment: ```-L``` defines the location of you library, ```-l``` is the compiled src, you can read about compiler flags in here https://caiorss.github.io/C-Cpp-Notes/compiler-flags-options.html

Comment: So `-L` and `-l` only work for shared libraries, not static? Otherwise, I believe I'm defining both of those flags correctly in my example.

Comment: is there any dynamic version of libtree-sitter in tree-sitter/ ? If so the linker will prefer it and won't use the static library

Comment: Call it `libtree-sitter.a`. The `-l` option prepends `lib` to the library file name it is looking for.

Comment: @IanAbbott the library name seems to be correct. `libtree-sitter.a` is exactly the name used in the first and working linker command

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Yes, you are right. I was way-layed by the wrong filename in the opening sentence!

Comment: no they are for both static or shared, did you add a  ```__attribute__``` to your code?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt You're right! There's a file called `libtree-sitter.dylib` present in the same directory. How do I prefer the static library then?

Comment: @IanAbbott Whoops, sorry about the wrong filename in the first line. I've edited the post.

Comment: I don't know clang. There might be a linker-switch like gcc's `-static` that should do the job

Comment: but anyway: if you want to have the library statically linked what's so bad about explicitly passing it to clang as you did in the first example?

Comment: try ```-L./ -ltree-sitter``` instead of ```-Ltree-sitter -ltree-sitter```, or  ```-L"your_path_folder_where_your_libtree-sitter_is_located" -ltree-sitter```

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt This may be getting out of the scope of the original question, but I was hoping there was a nice way to add libraries through the `LDFLAGS` Makefile variable so I was messing around with `-L` and `-l`. [Here](http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/articles/make/#a-makefile-for-99-of-your-programs) is the Makefile template I'm working with — do you have a neat way to include shared libraries explicitly? No worries if you do not; my original question has been answered thanks to you.

Comment: In that makefile nothing prevents you from adding "tree-sitter/libtree-sitter.a" to LDFLAGS, And generally if your linking static libraries you need to take the same care about parameter sequence whether you use -l or explicit path names

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtree-sitter.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/jason/Downloads/tree sitter test/test-json-parser
  Reason: image not found
```

- This gives you several hints about what is happening:  It says that it doesn't find `libtree-sitter.0.dylib` in directory `/usr/local/lib` which indicates that you have not specified a `-L` option to search in the subdirectory you say.

First of all, I recommend you to execute `clang` with option `-v` to show what command line is it using to call the linker.  This will probably don't show the `-L` option you specified and it's argument.

My guess is that you are using that command line in some script that is deleting some of the `\` chars (or you have a space after the `\`, and you are getting a new line cutting your command line before the linker options.  Check this.

The linker you are using will check all directories specified in `-L` options before any of the system directories, for a file called `lib`*yourLibraryName*`.`*number*`.dylib`, if it doesn't find, will try `lib`*yourLibraryName*`.a`, and then it will try the next directory in the list.  If you call the compiler with the `-v` option you will get the set of options it is using to call the linker.  Please, it would be nice if you include that in your question.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. A user in the comments under the post has already solved it — turns out there was a dynamic library with the same name as the static one, so the linker preferred the former. I had to link the static library explicitly without the `-l` flag.